# Nest js: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Season3Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I have the following error in nest. I've read the doc but I still don't understand what's going on. This is the full error: "[Nest] 9420  - 21/02/2022, 12:39:24 p. m.   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Season3Service (?). Please make sure that
the argument gModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context".  Here is my code:

app.controller.ts:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientRequest } from 'http';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Sarani Mukoe! En el Arco de la Villa del Herrero';
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Season3Controller } from './season3/season3.controller';
import { Season3Service } from './season3/season3.service';
import { Season3Module } from './season3/season3.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [Season3Module, MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/DemonSlayer')],
  controllers: [AppController, Season3Controller],
  providers: [AppService, Season3Service],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
```

Then, I have the season3 module folder:

season3.controller.ts:

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Put, Delete, Body, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateSeasonDto } from './dto/create-season.dto';
import { Season } from './interfaces/Season';
import { Season3Service } from "./season3.service";

@Controller('season3')
export class Season3Controller {

  constructor(private season3: Season3Service) {}

  @Get()
  getSeasons(): Promise<Season[]> {
    return this.season3.getSeasons();
  }

  @Get(':p')
  getSeason(@Param('p') id: string): Promise<Season>{
    console.log(id);
    
    return this.season3.getSeason(id);
  }

  @Post() 
  createSeason(@Body() season: CreateSeasonDto): string {
    console.log(
      `Título: ${season.titulo}. Cuerpo: ${season.cuerpo}. Realizado: ${season.realizado}`
    );
    return 'Insertando.... Hinokami Kagura';
  }

  @Put(':p1')
  updateSeason(@Body() cuerpo: CreateSeasonDto, @Param('p1') id): string {
    console.log(cuerpo);
    console.log(id);
    
    return `Actualizando.... Velocidad Extrema`;
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  deleteSeason(@Param('id') id): string { 
    console.log(id);
    
    return `Eliminando(${id}) .... Colmillos Afilados`;
  }
}
```

season3.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Season3Controller } from './season3.controller';
import { Season3Service } from './season3.service';
import { SeasonSchema} from "./schemas/season.schema";

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([
    {name:'g', schema:SeasonSchema}
  ])],
  controllers: [Season3Controller],
  providers: [Season3Service],
})
export class Season3Module {}
```

season3.service.ts:

```
import { Model } from "mongoose";
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Season } from "./interfaces/Season";

@Injectable()
export class Season3Service {

  constructor(@InjectModel('g') private seasonModel: Model<Season>) {}

  async getSeasons() {
    return await this.seasonModel.find();
  }

  async getSeason(id: string) {
    return await this.seasonModel.findById(id);
  }

}
```

Comment: Who provides `Model<Season>`?

Comment: Why do you have the `Season3Controller` and `Service` in **both** the `Season3Module` and `AppModule`?

Comment: Model<Season> is imported from the interfaces folder. This is the code:                                                     
 import { Document } from 'mongoose';
export interface Season extends Document{

  id?: number;
  numberSeason: number;
  nameArc: string;
  date: string;
  inEmision: boolean;

}

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I am new to nest. I was following a youtube tutorial and they did it this way

Comment: Well, that will tell Nest that you want to create two controllers and two services. This is most likely not what you're trying to do. Instead, your `Season3Module` should have `Season3Service` in the `providers` and `exports`. Now anything that imports `Season3Module` can have providers that make use of `Season3Service`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel sorry. I got a bit lost. how would i do this in code?

Comment: As it looks like you don't actually use the `Season3Service` in your `AppService` or anywhere outside of `Season3Module` just remove the `Season3` controller and service and just have the `Season3MOudle` in `AppModule`'s `imports`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel You are my hero. Now a query. I am interested in learning nest. I know Javascript well, but what are the requirements to learn nest? And what courses or sources would you recommend to learn it?

Comment: Read the docs, work on practice projects, pick up the official course if you want or a tutorial from Udemy. You don't really _need_ anything other than a will to learn and to take time to understand what you're writing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Season3Service` is not exported so you won't be able to use it in other modules.

in `season3.module.ts` add `export`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Season3Controller } from './season3.controller';
import { Season3Service } from './season3.service';
import { SeasonSchema} from "./schemas/season.schema";

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([
    {name:'g', schema:SeasonSchema}
  ])],
  controllers: [Season3Controller],
  providers: [Season3Service],
  exports: [Season3Service], // <----- make Season3Service public
})
export class Season3Module {}
```

doc: https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#shared-modules

After this, any other module that imports `Season3Module` will be able to inject (user) `Season3Service`

in `app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Season3Controller } from './season3/season3.controller';
import { Season3Module } from './season3/season3.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [Season3Module, MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/DemonSlayer')],
  controllers: [AppController, Season3Controller],
  providers: [AppService], // <---- remove Season3Service from providers
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now any *providers/controllers* in AppModule will have access to `Season3Service`